# Mesh pinching when smoothing vertex

Tags: vertices

I'm using a tutorial on a scuba diving tank for my game and when i try and smooth or change the vertices the mesh pinches

[image: before and after]

[image: image 2]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please explain more in detail what's the problem?

Comment: when you press ctrl and d together its supposed to add a sort of curve. well on thats specific column it freaks out and instead of smoothing out sort of folds on its self. as you can see on the photos instead of curving to it hits the vertices then curves out when its supposed to just curve out

Comment: Default control scheme Ctrl + D adds a driver to a property, are you using nonstandard keymapping?

Comment: no my control d works fine but the vertices are messing up on somethings in particular. i am a complete beginner and barely know much about blender

Comment: is there any way i can send you a link?

Comment: You can add your blend file to your question. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help)) Then we can look at it and see if that helps us figure out the issue.

Comment: Those look very much like duplicate vertices, to me..  M > Merge By Distance .. rack up the distance in F9 and see whether anything catches

Comment: ok. ill try it.

Comment: i cant figure it out. all the vertices are off. I'll just attach it to the question and maybe you can help me

Comment: if anyone can tell me where i went wrong, I'd be thankful

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the file and inspected the face direction (shown in the pic below).
[image]
It seems the normals around the pinching vertices are flipped around.

If I re-calculate the normals (in edit mode, select all with A, then press Ctrl+N) the pinching seems to go away.
[image]

Hopefully I understood you correctly, and that this helps.

Comment: thanks. that looks right so i'll go try it now.

Comment: thanks a bunch! it is working fine now. I appreciate the help!